# Powershell - clarification about foreach

Tags: powershell

I am learning powershell and I need someone to give me an initial push to get me through the learning curve. I am familiar with programming and dos but not powershell.

What I would like to do is listing all files from my designated directory and pushing the filenames into an array. I am not very familiar with the syntax and when I tried to run my test I was asked about entering parameters.

Could someone please enlighten me and show me the correct way to get what I want?

This is what powershell asked me:

```
PS D:\ABC> Test.ps1
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:
```

This is my test:

```
[string]$filePath = "D:\ABC\*.*";

Get-ChildItem $filePath | foreach
{
 $myFileList = $_.BaseName;
 write-host $_.BaseName
}
```

Why was ps asking about Process[0]?

I would want to ps to list all the files from the directory and pipe the results to foreach where I put each file into $myFileList array and print out the filename as well.

Comment: Bring the opening curly brace up a line so it's on the end of the foreach

Comment: The prompt is because it's expecting a scriptblock to be passed to the process parameter but you can't do the new line until after you've opened the script block

Comment: The var $myFileList is overwritten with every iteration. Use `$myFileList = Get-ChildItem $filePath` to fill it.

Comment: The PowerShell language is not like many other languages in that it is sensitive to newlines. This can make it cumbersome to use at times when a different layout for the expression would be more easily understood.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't confuse `foreach` (the statement) with `ForEach-Object` (the cmdlet). Microsoft does a terrible job with this because there is an alias of `foreach` that points to `ForEach-Object`, so when you use `foreach` you have to know which version you're using based on how you're using it. Their documentation makes this worse by further conflating the two.

The one you're trying to use in your code is `ForEach-Object`, so you should use the full name of it to differentiate it. From there, the issue is that the `{` block starts on the next line.

`{}` is used in PowerShell for blocks of code related to statements (like `while` loops) but is also used to denote a `[ScriptBlock]` object.

When you use `ForEach-Object` it's expecting a scriptblock, which can be taken positionally, but it must be on the same line.

Conversely, since `foreach` is a statement, it can use its `{}` on the next line.

Your code with `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem $filePath | ForEach-Object {
 $myFileList = $_.BaseName;
 write-host $_.BaseName
}
```

Your code with `foreach`:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $filePath
foreach ($file in $Files)
{
 $myFileList = $file.BaseName;
 write-host $file.BaseName
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. To further clarify (or possibly confuse) because you used foreach in the pipeline powershell used it as an alias of foreach-object instead of the foreach statement as demonstrated. But as Briantist says, best to be explicit to save confusion - in the pipeline it's always foreach-object (although it also has an alias of %).

Comment: @briantist: indeed I was not clear and confused. Thank you for the clarification. Thank you all for your hints/answers. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @user1205746 look at the comment from LotPings on your question as well. I didn't address that point in my answer but they're correct.

Comment: It does WHAT? But that's mad... Thanks for explaining.